# "Be aware and agree to" or "Be aware of and agree to"?

Tags: prepositions

What would be the correct form between the following:

> I am aware and agree to the ~

> I am aware of and agree to the ~

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show a fuller example usage? If you agree to something, no doubt you will be aware of it.

Comment: 'Be aware' can stand alone, but if used with actual reference to a fact (etc) needs 'of'.

Comment: [Both forms are used.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aware+and+agree+to%2Caware+of+and+agree+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) Strictly speaking it should be "aware **of**", because that's a different preposition to "agree **to**" (so you can't just "delete" it as a "predictably repeated element"). But personally I think it would be pedantic in the extreme to quibble about such matters outside of the "legal document" context.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the actual text is just like the example, followed by the name of the agreement (which I can't disclose).